# How to achieve this texture of jagged edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, filter

I am doing a project for my tech design class and we have to make spoof ads of already existing ads. What I'm trying to do is create the opposite effect of the refine edge command. I have tried some of the filters but none of them seem to have the correct effect. 
Below is the ad which I'm trying to replicate. I have everything down, except that the edges of the flame and the match are smooth since I used the pen tool.

How do I achieve this texture?

[image: The image in question]
http://tobaccopreventionk12.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/ignite1.gif

Comment: Sorry, I do not entirely understand. Is the image entirely your own creation? The jagged edges are surely due to the textured overall effect of the image?

Comment: This is the ad that the person is trying to replicate. They want to achieve the texture shown...as of now it is just smooth edges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather the **spatter** filter will solve your problem. Simply select Filter > Artistic > Spatter and toggle the preferences to where you deem fit. I have an example below of the 'jagged' result that I  achieved from doing this.

I also added a hint of sandstone texture to mimic that of the cardboard, there are options such as canvas either that you might deem more suitable. (Filter > Texture)

Naturally there is noise, lighting, text shadow etc. to consider with this image, I did not take these into account as I did not think that they were a part of what you were having issues with.

Below are the results that I got from the 2 filters mentioned, hope this helps!

[image: Assumed before, filter sample, desired result]